# md5 hash only first 512 bytes of file

Tags: shell-script, hashsum, data

### Background

I am about to migrate files from my old NAS to a new one, and want to verify the data integrity. The old NAS (Debian) is using Linux Ext3 file system, whilst the new one (FreeNAS) is based on ZFS. To speed up the integrity validation I am trying to use the triage approach:

- first validate all file sizes
- secondly md5 hash the first 512 bytes of each file
- lastly md5 hash entire file

The idea being that the first two steps would filter out obviously corrupted files, and be much quicker to detect than running md5 in bulk for TB of files.

### **Question**

I have constructed a bash command for performing a md5 hash of a directory structure, and sorting the output based on file name to ensure a deterministic order on my Linux NAS.

```
#find somedir -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 34;
12e761f96223145aa63f4f48f252d7fb  /somedir/foo.txt
18409feb00b6519c891c751fe2541fdc  /somedir/bar.txt
```

But how to modify above if I want to md5 only the first 512 bytes of each file?

Comment: This strategy is counterproductive unless you expect a significant number of corrupted files. Just calculate all the hashes, it'll be faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `dd` to pipe only the first 512 bytes to `md5sum`. However this will cause `md5sum` to be oblivious of the filename, so in addition replace `-` with the filename again.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "dd if={} bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | md5sum | sed s\|-\|{}\|" \; | sort -k 34;
```

Comment: Tried it out and it works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: This command fails with files having special characters.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me. The `{}` inside the `exec` was failing for files with special characters. Hence, I instead used GNU `parallel` (install its latest version to make the following solution work).

Using `parallel`, the `{}` didn't misbehave for files with special characters. Also, `parallel` made the whole process much faster as it distributes the processes across multiple cores. Here is what worked for me using `parallel`:

```shell
find . -type f | parallel 'dd if={} bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | md5sum | tr -d "\n"; echo {};' | sort -k34;
```